# ExpressJS routing with different parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two routes : app.use serves the static files.

```
 app.use('/test', earlyAccess(), express.static(path.join(__dirname, staticFolder)))

app.get("/test", callback);
app.get("/test/:id", callback);

// Here is the callback
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(staticFolder + '/test.html');
fileStream.on('open', function () {
  fileStream.pipe(res);
});
```

From the browser, if I call  `localhost:80/test/1` - works fine.
but if I call `localhost:80/test` - it gets redirected to main page. In the server console, I got 304 warning.

How  to use routes based on parameter in expressjs?

Comment: 304 only indicate as the document it was not modified. What's callback in `/test` do?

Comment: loads a HTML. test/:id and /test loads the same html page.

Comment: Do you can provide the callback function?!

Comment: I created a simple Express project and can run the code successfully: both "/test" and "/test/:id" router can return test.html to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) instead `fs.createReadStream`, something like:

```
res.sendFile('test.html');
```

Comment: The issue is it never hits the callback for /test.

Comment: No makes sense, has more routes besides these two? Anyway, res.sendFile is better than fs.createReadStream, for returns files.

Comment: I don't understand.what  do you meant by more routes? /test or /test/1 should load the html page for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for request parameters within the callback,

```
app.get('/test', callback);
app.get('/test/123', callback);

// callback
if(req.params.second) {
  // code for route with param. - /test/123
}
else {
// code for route without param. - /test
}
```

Parameters in the request are stored in req.params as

```
{first:'NameOfRoute', second:'NextParam'} ...
```

So here,

```
{first:'test', second:'123'}
```

Comment: I got it. but it never hits the callback.

Answer (score -3):

you can try it like this:

```
app.use("/test/*", (req, res, next) => {
   // your callback(req, res);
   next();
});
app.get("/test/:id", callback);
```

`app.use`, mean you can write a middleware, and it will call next();

Comment: And, how does this answer the original question?

Comment: This not se apply for the problem, it's generalization the route.

Comment: var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(staticFolder + '/test.html');
    fileStream.on('open', function () {
      fileStream.pipe(res);
    });